# C# Timespan - User defined customer format specifier

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way I can extend the timespan custom format specifiers(refer below documentation URL) with my own new ones?

Doc Url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Maybe something like 'ww' to display "Total Minutes"

```
var myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 10);
Console.Writeline(myTimeSpan.ToString("ww:ss"));
```

Expected result for above code would be:

```
80:10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an implementation for [ICustomFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icustomformatter?view=net-5.0). You have to provide that implementation when you're converting to a string. There is a caveat in that simply calling the [ToString overload on the TimeSpan that accepts an IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) is not going to work due to the fact it always expects a DateTimeFormatInfo instance.

Here is a CustomFormatter that does what you want:

```
class TotalMinutesFormatter:ICustomFormatter, IFormatProvider
{
    // IFormatProvider.GetFormat 
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        //return ourself
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }
    
    // ICustomFormatter.Format fmt will have ww:ss and value will be the TimeSpan
    public string Format(string fmt, object value, IFormatProvider fp)
    {
      if (value is TimeSpan) {
         var ts = (TimeSpan) value;
         var sb = new StringBuilder();
         switch(fmt)
         {
            case "ww:ss":
                // calc minutes
                var minutes = ts.Hours*60+ts.Minutes;
                sb.AppendFormat("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, ts.Seconds);
                break;
            default:
                // non recognized format
                sb.AppendFormat(fmt,value);
            break;
         }
         return sb.ToString(); // the TimeSpan as string
      }
      // default fallback
      return String.Format(fmt,value);
    }
}
```

And here is how you need to use the formatter:

```
var myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 10);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new TotalMinutesFormatter(), "{0:ww:ss}", myTimeSpan));
```

Again, doing  `myTimeSpan.ToString("ww:ss", new TotalMinutesFormatter())` will not work and lead to a FormatException:

> Input string was not in a correct format

The internal implementation of TimeSpan.ToString doesn't honor a CustomFormatter if you provided one.

Comment: Hi Rene. Thank you for your detailed answer. Using an ICustomFormatter seems to be the closest one can get. However, it wont serve the purpose entirely though since ToString() wont work and I believe this cant be used in XAML either.